# Determining whether a set is open or closed

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following set: $B = \left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}: 0<x\leq1, y\geq2\right\}$

I know that that a set is open if for every point in that set there is a number $\epsilon$ such that a ball of radius $\epsilon$ around that point is a subset of the set, and closed if it contains its limit points. Looking at this set, I can find examples of limit points it contains, and limit points it doesn't contain. For example, the set contains the point $(1,2)$ but doesn't contain the point $(0,2)$. So I want to say it's neither closed nor open. But I'm fairly sure this is incorrect. What am I missing here?

Comment: Ok, I've edited my question. Can you address the set $B$, please? A more specific hint would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the contrary, your reasoning is entirely correct, although I believe there is some mistake on your definition of open set, since open means that any point has a neighborhood contained on the set. Open and closed sets are not exhaustive in general, so you can have sets which are not open nor closed, a simpler example being $(0,1]$ in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Okay, now that you edited the question I guess everything is fine :)

Comment: I'm just confused because in the context of the question I was given for homework, each set was supposed to be either open or closed. This is neither.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't know about your homework specifically, but I can most certainly tell you that the set is not closed (for instance (0,3) is a limit point and does not belong to the set) nor open (there is no ball around (1,2) contained in the set). Some typo somewhere maybe?

Comment: Potentially. Thank you!